# Issue with focus() after detach and insertBefore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with using the Tab key to move through the fields when I detach the current focussed element and insert it again. Please find my code in [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/UjE9W/). Also see below:

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formElem').focusin(function() {
        // Remove default text on focus in
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('defaultText');
            if (($(this).attr('id') == 'reg_pwd') || ($(this).attr('id') == 'reg_conf_pwd')) {
                id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
                marker = $('<span>123</span>').insertBefore($(this));
                $(this).detach().attr('type', 'password').insertAfter(marker);
                marker.remove();

            }
            if ($(this).get(0) != $(':focus').get(0)) {
                $(this).focus();
            }
        }
    }).focusout(function() {
        // Remove default text on focus out
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('defaultText');
            if (($(this).attr('id') == 'reg_pwd') || ($(this).attr('id') == 'reg_conf_pwd')) {
                marker = $('<span>123</span>').insertBefore($(this));
                $(this).detach().attr('type', 'text').insertAfter(marker);
                marker.remove();
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

The code changes the type of the field from text to password and back and forth. When you click or use Tab to reach the password field, it loses the focus after it has been added again. Thanks if somebody can figure out why.

Comment: I was just puzzling the same thing in JSFiddle.  Does the HTML5 placeholder attribute not disolve the need for this type of code?

Comment: it's not clear what he's trying to do with the 123 span.  Also, some browsers (i.e. MSIE) won't let you change the type of an input once it has been created.

Comment: The span acts as a marker for reinserting the element. I have not researched about MSIE, just exploring this technique.

Comment: ah, so the "plain" input is just there so you can show some text and then when it gets focus you change to a real password input?

Comment: @Pradeep what's the 123 marker for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your using html5, so perhaps you could take advantage of the `placeholder` attribute. Instead of `<input value="blah" />` use `<input placeholder="blah" />`. Now you don't even need to have the defaultText class, so you can remove that, along with associated jquery code you have that removes and adds classes.

Now you can also change the `<input type="text" />` to `<input type="password" />` for the password fields. I'm not sure what your trying to do with `<span>123</span>`. So perhaps, I don't fully understand your question. But the below seems to accomplish the effect your trying to do.

A jsfiddle as well http://jsfiddle.net/8BBRC/2

edit: Had wrong jsfiddle link.

```
<input type="text" class="formElem" id="reg_fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" title="Full Name" /><br />
<input type="email" class="formElem" id="reg_email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" title="Email Address" /><br />
<input type="password" class="formElem" id="reg_pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Confirm" title="Password" /><br />
<input type="password" class="formElem" id="reg_conf_pwd" name="conf_pwd" placeholder="Confirm Password" title="Confirm Password" /><br />
<input type="submit" id="reg_submit" value="Submit" /><br />
```